# Indices trick used for several components

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, indices

Consider this fully working code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename IndexPack> struct Make;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T... Indices>
struct Make<T, P<Indices...>> {
    using type = P<(Indices+1)..., (-3*Indices)..., (Indices-1)...>;
};

template <int...> class Pack;

int main() {
    static_assert (std::is_same<Make<int, Pack<1,2,3,4>>::type, 
        Pack<2,3,4,5, -3,-6,-9,-12, 0,1,2,3>>::value, "false");
}
```

What I actually want the output to be is

```
Pack<2,-3,0, 3,-6,1, 4,-9,2, 5,-12,3>
```

instead of `Pack<2,3,4,5, -3,-6,-9,-12, 0,1,2,3>`.  I first tried

```
using type = P<(Indices+1, -3*Indices, Indices-1)...>;
```

but that is simply understood by the compiler to be a useless comma operator.  What is the desired syntax to get what I want?  If there is no such syntax, what is the cleanest way to do this, keeping in mind that using `Indices` 3 times is just an example (we may want to use it more than 3 times).  Please don't tell me that I have to write a helper to extract the individual packs and then "interlace" all the elements.  That nightmarish method cannot be the best solution (and such a solution would also only work if we knew exactly how many individual packs to extract).

Would defining

```
template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T I>
struct Component {
    using type = P<I+1, -3*I, I-1>;
};
```

help somehow?  Make a pack expansion on this?

Comment: I'm not sure writing a function to do something is so nightmarish -- it's exactly what you would do if you were trying to do the same sort of thing at *runtime*.

Comment: @Hurkyl.  It's not so nightmarish actually, you're right.  But Columbo's solution below is far better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can concat recursively:

```
template <typename, typename, typename> struct Concat;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T... A, T... B>
struct Concat<T, P<A...>, P<B...>> {
    using type = P<A..., B...>;
};

template <typename T, typename IndexPack> struct Make;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T... I, T F >
struct Make<T, P<F, I...>> {
    using type = typename Concat<T,
                                 typename Make<T, P<F>>::type,
                                 typename Make<T, P<I...>>::type>::type;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T I>
struct Make<T, P<I>> {
    using type = P<I+1, -3*I, I-1>;
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9127edcc7d97ce3c)

Comment: @orlp I know how it feels.

Answer (score 0):

This was inspired by Columbo's solution.  It uses the pack expansion syntax that I originally sought, namely

```
using type = typename Merge<T, typename Component<T, P, Indices>::type...>::type;
```

As a result, now `Make` is reusable, first using `Triple`, and then using `Quadruple`, so any number of usages of `Indices` can be expanded simultaneously.  Here `Component` is a template-template-template parameter passed into `Make`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Packs> struct Merge;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P1, template <T...> class P2, T... Is, T... Js>
struct Merge<T, P1<Is...>, P2<Js...>> {
    using type = P1<Is..., Js...>;
};

template <typename T, typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct Merge<T, Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> {
    using type = typename Merge<T, Pack1, typename Merge<T, Pack2, Packs...>::type>::type;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T I>
struct Triple {
    using type = P<I+1, -3*I, I-1>;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, T I>
struct Quadruple {
    using type = P<I+1, -3*I, I-1, I>;
};

template <typename T, typename IndexPack,
    template <typename U, template <U...> class P, U I> class Component> struct Make;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Indices,
    template <typename U, template <U...> class P, U I> class Component>
struct Make<T, Z<Indices...>, Component> {
    using type = typename Merge<T, typename Component<T, Z, Indices>::type...>::type;
};

template <int...> class Pack;

int main() {
    static_assert (std::is_same<Make<int, Pack<1,2,3,4>, Triple>::type,
        Pack<2,-3,0, 3,-6,1, 4,-9,2, 5,-12,3>>::value, "false");

    static_assert (std::is_same<Make<int, Pack<1,2,3,4>, Quadruple>::type,
        Pack<2,-3,0,1, 3,-6,1,2, 4,-9,2,3, 5,-12,3,4>>::value, "false");
}
```